# Button click event is not working when inflated layout is used

Tags: android

Please can anyone help me, since i am new to android i am not able to get solution for - the button OnClick event is not working if i use the inflated layout. Here is my usemerge.xml code,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#2996ff" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/i1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >
    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

toplayout.xml

```
   <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/butt1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton" 
        android:text="@string/schedule" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 private  LinearLayout lin1; 
  private Button bt1;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.usemerge);

     final LayoutInflater  inflater =       
    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      lin1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.i1);
        View vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.toplayout,lin1,false);

        lin1.addView(vi);
        bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View vo) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent ain=new Intent(getBaseContext(), ScheduleActivity.class);
                startActivity(ain); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why is `Button bt1=(Button)lin1.findViewById(R.id.butt1);` commented?

Comment: what is exact error shown under logcat ?

Comment: But where did you initialize your `bt1`??

Comment: Button bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1);

Comment: @AnushaAlandkar why you commented bt1 initialization line?

Comment: @AnushaAlandkar write this line: Button bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1); may be it will work for you.

Comment: sorry its not commented.. i forgot to change it

Comment: @AnushaAlandkar Ya then change it as per given above.

Comment: even if i uncomment that line its not working please help me in solving this issue

Comment: use `Button bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1);` @AnushaAlandkar

Comment: @AnushaAlandkar are see above I said, Button bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1) write this line

Comment: even if i include vi its not working

Comment: any error are you getting ? @AnushaAlandkar

Comment: try with `View vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.toplayout,null,false);`

Comment: even if i include line View vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.toplayout,null,false); its not working

Comment: i am also using scrollview in usermerge whether this effects..

Comment: @AnushaAlandkar have you done this?

Comment: your code is working...

Answer (score 0):

Define activity in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name=".ScheduleActivity"/>
```

Set click listener before add Button to LinearLayout :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LinearLayout lin1;
    private Button bt1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.usemerge);

        lin1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.i1);
        View vi = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toplayout, lin1, false);
        bt1 = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View vo) {
                Intent ain = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class);
                startActivity(ain);
            }
        });
        lin1.addView(vi);
    }

}
```

Comment: i also posted that answer but someone give downvate i m relly shok to see this

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems ...

The first is that you have commented out the find for the Button.

```
Button bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1);
```

The second is that you have the onclick function calling the startActivity of the activity in an anonymous interface.  There are two solutions you can do.

First is to implement the interface onClickListener in the MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements Button.onClickListener {
    //Your code Goes here...
      bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
    //Rest of your code

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
       Intent ain = new Intent(this, ScheduleActivity.class);
       startActivity(ain);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can also do the following in your onclick:

```
Intent ain = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(ain);
```

Comment: Can you post the error messages? It may be something else.  Additionally you should try looking into the xml merge tags and include tags that basically does the same thing you try to do with the layout inflater.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you do `setContentView(R.layout.usemerge);` at the beginning, and after that you do your inflate and bind the button to the inflated view, this mean that you don't see the inflated layout anyway (the button that u see on the screen isn't **bt1** from inflated view).

You should do `setContentView(vi);` after inflating the view.

Comment: where should i include this setContentView(vi);

Comment: u can setContentView(vi); after inflating , and remove setContentView(R.layout.usemerge);

Answer (score 0):

Define Your `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ScheduleActivity">
```

Instead of `getBaseContext()` use this line

```
Intent ain=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class);
```

**Implement the interface `OnClickListener` like this**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private  LinearLayout lin1; 
      private Button bt1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final LayoutInflater  inflater =       
        (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          lin1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.i1);
            View vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sub,lin1,false);

            lin1.addView(vi);
            bt1=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.butt1);
            bt1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent ain=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubActivity.class);
         startActivity(ain); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setContentView(vi);` after **inflating** , and remove `setContentView(R.layout.usemerge);`

Answer (score -1):

Your MainActivity.java should look like this:

```
LinearLayout lin1;
Button bt1;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.usemerge);

 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toplayout, null, true);
 bt1 = inflater.findViewById(R.id.butt1);

 lin1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.i1);
 View vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.toplayout,lin1,false);

    lin1.addView(vi);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View vo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent ain=new Intent(getBaseContext(), ScheduleActivity.class);
            startActivity(ain); 
        }
    });
```