# How to decrease button click area?

Tags: android

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903247/button-click-event-is-not-working-when-inflated-layout-is-used) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176105/how-to-increase-hit-area-of-android-button-without-scaling-background) about some methods to *increase* the button's click area. But my problem is the opposite. The button is `100x100 px`, and when I click outside of it (on a `RelativeLayout`) the button gets clicked (changes to its `pressed` state).

I tried putting it inside a `LinearLayout` set to `wrap_content` (hoping to separate it from the background), but that didn't work.

I also tried to set its `padding` to 0. Didn't work.

`android:duplicateParentState="false"` didn't work as well.

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you post some for your code....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this. It worked for me.

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
```

There is a minimum touch area saved already, of approx 50dp. So that it is clickable.
Use these lines, and then set the values you would like.